# A formula for $\sum^n_{i=1}(1+1/n)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, harmonic-numbers

Find a formula for 
$$\sum^n_{i=1}\left(1 + \dfrac{1}{n}\right)$$
Prove that it holds for all $n \geq 1$. It kind of looks like is a series but I didn't succeed in this problem. Can someone help me please. Thanks.

Comment: Have you heard of Harmonic numbers?

Comment: This has no closed form solution

Comment: @Sanath, your editing has changed the question --- do you know for a fact that OP wanted $1/i$ and not $1/n$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I believed that it was a typo. I'll revert it back to $1/n$.

Comment: It might be safer to ask OP what was intended.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you effectively want to explicit $$S=\sum^n_{i=1}\left(1 + \dfrac{1}{n}\right)$$ just think about what you do when summing. You just write $$S=\sum^n_{i=1}\left(1 + \dfrac{1}{n}\right)=\left(1 + \dfrac{1}{n}\right)+\left(1 + \dfrac{1}{n}\right)+\left(1 + \dfrac{1}{n}\right)+...+\left(1 + \dfrac{1}{n}\right)$$ what you made $n$ times. So the result of the summation is $S=\left(1 + \dfrac{1}{n}\right) \times n=(n+1)$.

Since you did not clarify the question, we could also have considered  $$S=\sum^n_{i=1}\left(1 + \dfrac{1}{i}\right)$$ which is a very different story. For this case, expanding we have $$S=\sum^n_{i=1} 1 +\sum^n_{i=1}\dfrac{1}{i}=n+H_n$$ where appears the harmonic number.